# Contacts Showing DidNotMeetEntryCriteria Status

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I have created a WelcomeEmail DE which having 2 fields

- EmailAddress  (EmailAddress)
- IsActive      (Boolean)

Mapped EmailAddress to SubscriberKey

I have linked ContactKey to EmailAddress in Population and added the EmailAddress field in Contacts Configuration.

Created Entry Event using Event Data and set criteria `[EmailAddress IsNotNull]`. After activating the journey in Test mode, I'm firing an event using Automation Studio.

**Problem:**

1. When I checked the Event result in Test Mode I see all my records are rejected and showing DidNotMeetEntryCriteria status.
2. i also remove old records and import new records in my DE, and fire the event and getting same result.

I know it is very simple journey and did not face this type of problem earlier and also, understand it was failing because of not matching event criteria but this is not the case, Event criteria is matching 100% for all my records.

Can someone help me here and advise where is the problem in my Journey Setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some struggle finally, journey is working fine now. `The issue was Test mode`, i was testing a journey in test mode and for the some reason it's not injecting contact in test mode.

I have activated journey now in active mode and finally, Journey entry event injecting contact successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If my guess is correct, in the Event entry filter criteria, you should have mapped wrong email addresss field filter criteria.

When you root a data extension, MC creates two additional fields Email address and subscriber key for its processing. You must have used this field for Entry criteria validation and the records should have failed the processing. If you correct the entry criteia to map to the proper DE email address field, it should work properly.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh! If EmailAddress field is already present in the DE then MC create only one additional field i.e. SubscriberKey and I mapped DataExtension EmailAddress field in Event entry criteria.

Comment: Also, I have fire the event without using Event entry criteria (Event entry criteria is optional in JB) and received same status message i.e. DidNotMeetEntryCriteria.