# Journey Builder error "DidNotMeetEntryCriteria"

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I have data extension where I have defined two fields as primary key (tested with one key as well) and DE added to contact builder. We send lot of emails daily and this is our normal drill.

But some how for this DE when I fire event no contact added to journey builder and when I view event results I can see all the contacts evaluated for journey, none accepted (all rejected), rejected contact view show status "DidNotMeetEntryCriteria" there is no entry criteria or filter.

I tried many options adding DE to attribute group,  tried to inject without adding to attribute group, creating a simple journey without any email in the journey.
But every time I get status it is either "Failed" or "DidNotMeetEntryCriteria"
I have no entry criteria and selected correct email for the journey if I am using email in the journey.

Please let me know if anyone have have knowledge of this issue.

Best

Comment: Is the Data Extension mapped to the Contact Key in Contact Builder correctly?

Comment: Yes it  does as I said I have tried to map/connect with as single PK as well as two fields as PK in DE.

Comment: I have also faced same issue but now its working fine. 
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149808/contacts-showing-didnotmeetentrycriteria-status/151579#151579

Comment: Also, did you create Population and Contacts Configuration in Contact Builder?

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this problem and according to salesforce engineers it was caused by an issue in the contact data model. If this is the problem, I'm afraid you need to reach out to salesforce support team. A fix will be released on 27th January ([Release Notes: January 2017 Release](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/january_2017_release/)).

Here you can find the possibly related issue: ['Contacts Registration Failed' Marketing Cloud Connect error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/152501/36218)